# Can I take a feral cat with me when I move?

Tags: cats, feral, house-moving

I have been feeding a feral cat for four years now; I live in a apartment complex and will be moving to a house. This cat doesn't trust anyone and runs every time. I get lucky and he will let me touch him and pet him. But picking him up, he is not having it. So now my question is, can I catch him and take him with me? It will break my heart to leave him behind.